# GUI v0.13.0.3 does not start on Mac OS X (monero-wallet-gui cannot be opened because of a problem - Library missing)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

A full report of this particular issue can be found here:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/1658

Is there any quick resolutions I can use?

Comment: on the windows version, my daemon stops and says disconnected.. is this normal.. if so how long would it take to connect?

Comment: @EtherealBlockchain - This comment probably applies to your situation too:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/9oim67/monero_gui_v01303_not_opening_on_mac_osx_1014/e806riz/?context=3

Comment: did anyone test this GUI v0.13.0.4? I downloaded 0.13.0.4 but it still does not work.

Comment: @Ebonit - are you absolutely certain that you downloaded GUI v0.13.0.4? If not, please use the direct download link from this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/9ti2on/gui_v01304_beryllium_bullet_released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular issue is fixed in GUI v0.13.0.4, which can be found here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/9ti2on/gui_v01304_beryllium_bullet_released/

<s>You can, most likely, resolve this issue by following selsta's suggestion here:</s>

https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/1658#issuecomment-430211706

Alternatively, you can try this suggestion:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/9oim67/monero_gui_v01303_not_opening_on_mac_osx_1014/e7untov/

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue is fixed in GUI v0.13.0.4, which can be found here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/9ti2on/gui_v01304_beryllium_bullet_released/

<s>Quick workaround:</s>

```
$ sudo -i 

root# mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p/lib/ 

root# ln -s /Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p/lib/
```